# Reusable Cell for UITableView not showing label text

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I'm attempting to use a reusable cell for the TableView control in Xamarin.IOS.
I've placed a table view on to my storyboard.

Then I set the `Prototype Cells` property to 1.
I then selected the UITableViewCell (which shows after setting the `Prototype Cells` property) and gave it the identifier "MainTableViewCell".

I expected when I ran this program to see a populated list with 40 items with the values of "Table item x" (x being the value of i set in a for loop).

But what I see instead in a list containing 40 items (which is correct) but the TextLabel does not show any text, each cell is blank.

The call to `DequeueReusableCell` is returning a non null value so I'm unsure why I'm unable to see the label text in the IOS simulator. I see no errors in the build output so any help would be appreciated.

**ViewController**

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    private List<string> _tableItems;

    protected ViewController( IntPtr handle ) : base( handle )
    {
        _tableItems = new List<string>( );
        for ( int i = 0; i < 40; i++ )
        {
            _tableItems.Add( $"Table item {i}" );
        }

    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad( )
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad( );
        MainTableView.Source = new MainTableViewSource( _tableItems );
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning( )
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning( );
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }
}
```

**MainTableViewSource**

```
public class MainTableViewSource : UITableViewSource
{
    private List<string> _items;
    private const string CallIdentifier = "MainTableViewCell";

    public MainTableViewSource( params string[ ] items )
    {
        _items = new List<string>( items );
    }

    public MainTableViewSource( IEnumerable<string> items )
        : this( items.ToArray( ) ) { }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell( UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath )
    {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell( CallIdentifier );
        if ( cell is null )
        {
            cell = new UITableViewCell( UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CallIdentifier );
        }
        cell.TextLabel.Text = _items[ indexPath.Row ];
        return cell;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection( UITableView tableview, nint section ) => _items.Count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK figured it out.
I didn't constrain the table so the cells label was off of the screen.
Once I constrained the table I was able to see the cells label.